# Way to clean up this pattern? Using private bool flag to denote when user changes UI vs when the class changes UI?

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls

I find myself using this pattern often

```
private boolean cbDeviceIndexInternal = false;
private void cbDevices_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!cbDeviceIndexInternal)
        DeviceChanged();
    cbDeviceIndexInternal = false;
}
...
cbDeviceIndexInternal = true;
cbDevices.SelectedIndex = 0;
```

As a result of the `SelectedIndex` being changed an event is thrown no matter if the index is changed by the user or by the class itself. I really hate using this code but it is the best solution I have found.

*Has anyone else encountered this, how did you solve it?*

Comment: You could also dynamically add/remove the `SelectedIndexChanged` event handler, but this is as annoying as the "flag" solution.

Comment: I've not used it but the [ComboBox.SelectionChangeCommitted](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.selectionchangecommitted(v=vs.110).aspx) event looks interesting.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp Hmm, I've never seen that event. It could be useful in the situation in the code above but I do have other example where I might be using a `TextBox` or `RadioButton` that I don't think have an equivalent event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't necessarily have to add *and* remove the handlers. Just don't add the handlers until the end of the `Load` event. That way they aren't present and firing while you're making programmatic changes to your controls.

Comment: This is all fine, unless changes take place after the `Load` event, too. For example "whenever a new value is selectedin the first combo box, a change should be made in the second".

Comment: I guess this is a good partial solution, I've never thought of this. But I do have cases where I might programmatically change UI controls after the `Form` has loaded.

Comment: It's a hair-splitting detail but I would lean toward adding and removing handlers because the job of the handlers is just to execute, not to question whether or not they should be executing. It might even make sense to put all of the "add handlers" in one function and the "remove handlers" in another, and call both functions at the right times during the page cycle. That way it makes the behavior much more explicit and easy to follow.

Comment: I like that idea, call them `Start/StopInteralUIChange` or something along those lines.